# How to make the first option in a woocommerce select field unselectable?

Tags: php, wordpress, select, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use a php function in wordpress to add a custom selectfield to my woocommerce checkout.
I want to make the first option (named blank) unselectable. How can i achieve this?

---

```
     woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_leeftijd'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
            'label'         => __('Leeftijd bij start Summer Camp'),
            'required' => true,
            'options'       => array(
                 'blank'     => __( 'Selecteer', 'njengah' ),
                 '4'         => __( '4', 'njengah' ),
                 '5'         => __( '5', 'njengah' ),
                 '6'         => __( '6', 'njengah' ),
                 '7'         => __( '7', 'njengah' ),
                 '8'         => __( '8', 'njengah' ),
                 '9'         => __( '9', 'njengah' ),
                 '10'        => __( '10', 'njengah' ),
                 '11'        => __( '11', 'njengah' )
        )), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_leeftijd'.$i ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing **disabled** attribute to the first option would do the trick.
You can check the woocommerce_form_field() function mechanism to check in which way it supports passing the disabled attribute.

You can even do this by jquery. Through your custom class my-field-class

```
$(".my-field-class select option:first").attr("disabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a placholder variable like this:

```
 woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_leeftijd'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
            'label'         => __('Leeftijd bij start Summer Camp'),
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder'   => __( 'Selecteer', 'njengah' ),
            'options'       => array(
                 '4'         => __( '4', 'njengah' ),
                 '5'         => __( '5', 'njengah' ),
                 '6'         => __( '6', 'njengah' ),
                 '7'         => __( '7', 'njengah' ),
                 '8'         => __( '8', 'njengah' ),
                 '9'         => __( '9', 'njengah' ),
                 '10'        => __( '10', 'njengah' ),
                 '11'        => __( '11', 'njengah' )
        )), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_leeftijd'.$i ));
```